# Select Option Shows Div & hides a Div - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Select Option

```
<select class="input_select" name="customer_type" id="central_company">
    <option value="standard">Standard</option>
    <option value="central">Central Station</option>
</select>
```

and a button

```
<div class="standardbutton">
     <label class="button_label">
         <input type="submit" class="standardbutton" name="button1" value="Submit Form" />
     </label>
</div>
```

That when clicked uses this Jquery

```
// Show Special Form Elements
$(".cleantestbox").hide();
$('#central_company').change(function() {
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('.cleantestbox').toggle(option.hasClass('central'));
    $('.standardbutton').toggle(option.hasClass('standard'));
}).change();
```

to hide the standard button class and show a div called .cleantestbox but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas it worked before but can't seem to find whats causing it not to work.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get in the console?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Put your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: No Errors just when I select the central nothing happens and the standardbutton div doesn't show up by default either

Comment: Here's your code: http://jsfiddle.net/DdMZV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Show Special Form Elements
$(".cleantestbox").hide();
$('#central_company').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'central') {
    $('.cleantestbox').show();
    $('.standardbutton').hide();
  } else {
    $('.cleantestbox').hide();
    $('.standardbutton').show();
  }
});
```